# Thunderbolt failure, all USB ports stop working. AER: can't recover

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, thinkpad, thunderbolt

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 5 with a fully updated Kubuntu 23.10/KDE/X11 session. I have two external monitors and a bunch of devices connected via a Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock. Every once in a while, my laptop just gives up all devices connected through the dock except the monitors. The monitors continue to work normally. The keyboard, mouse, mic, camera etc stop working.

It is fixed only after a restart, and everything works normally, until this randomly happens again! This is what I see in the syslog when this happens:

```
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683555+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756620] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Uncorrected (Fatal) error received: 0000:20:00.0
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683571+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756627] pcieport 0000:20:00.0: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Uncorrected (Fatal), type=Inaccessible, (Unregistered Agent ID)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683574+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756632] thunderbolt 0000:22:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683576+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756634] xhci_hcd 0000:25:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683576+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756636] xhci_hcd 0000:27:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.683585+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.756638] xhci_hcd 0000:56:00.0: AER: can't recover (no error_detected callback)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.831614+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.901452] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: Root Port link has been reset (0)
2024-02-13T22:01:19.831629+05:30 Matrix kernel: [ 1546.901485] pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: device recovery failed
2024-02-13T22:01:19.858448+05:30 Matrix krunner[5864]: error: v4l2-input: /dev/video4: select timed out
2024-02-13T22:01:19.858592+05:30 Matrix krunner[5864]: error: v4l2-input: /dev/video4: failed to log status
2024-02-13T22:01:20.025147+05:30 Matrix krunner[5864]: error: v4l2-input: /dev/video4: select timed out
```

kernel version: `6.5.0-17-generic (64-bit)`

How do I fix this or avoid this from happening?
Alternatively, is there a way I can recover from this error without a restart?